# iOS Amazon Cognito Sign-In Error InvalidParameterException

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am working on Amazon cognito for `iOS` with `user identity`. I integrated `AWSCore` and `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider` frameworks in my project and I successfully signed up with that. It also updates the `Users` and `Groups` in the `User Pools session`.

The problem I am facing is, while trying to sign-in with the same `credentials` I get the error: `InvalidParameterException` Only custom auth(lambda driven) is enabled for this client...

Anyone have idea on this. I have tried to configure `Lambda`. But no idea on how to do. Please suggest a possible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you in User Pool App section, You have checked "Only allow Custom Authentication (CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY)" to true for your app client.
Are you trying to setup your own authentication flow, instead of username and password based authentication provided by user pool?

If yes, you can find more details about custom authentication here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-custom-authentication-flow

If not, you can uncheck this option for your app client and error should go away.